# Hydrostatic pressure on submerged surface

Tags: fluid

Can someone help me calculate the hydrostatic pressure on an immersed inclined body like the one in the figure?

[image]

I know the force acting on the triangle is changing with height thus I can use an integral. Something like

$F = \int_0^{h1} \rho \cdot g \cdot y \cdot \frac{L}{sin(\alpha)} dy$

Where L is the length of the triangle on the screen. However, I don't know how to include the height above the triangle (h-h1). Can I just add this into the integral as this is constant?

Comment: So, what have you considered so far? This is not a free homework completion service - you have to show some effort.

Comment: I've made an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

$p$ represents the hydrostatic pressure at the boundary point. The force per unit width is simply $\dfrac{(p_1 + p_0)*L}{2}$. Wish this helps.